# Object Tracking using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video clip with fish swimming in a flume and small particles floating on the surface. So, the moving objects are the swimming fish and hundreds of particles. Here is the link of the [video sample](https://youtu.be/2DejhDJAcgs).

My interest is to locate the fish correctly in each single frame.

**Currently, my procedures are as below:**

1. remove light reflection (moving noise) in each single frame by converting RGB to HSV color space.
2. apply background subtraction method `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG`.
3. use erosion and dilation to remove most of the moving particle noise.
4. find all contours of the blobs in binary images, and compute rotated bounding boxes for all blobs.
5. compute aspect ratios for all rotated bounding boxes.
6. identify fish in the foreground frames by using simple criteria: if a blob occupies more than 1 pixel, then check the aspect ratio of its rotated bounding box. If it has the largest aspect ratio, it is considered as fish.

My questions are:

1. In the first 10 frames, the moving fish is not identified by the `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG`, I adjusted `history`, `nmixture` in the function, it does not seems to work well in the first 10 frames. **How to pick up the moving objects in the first few frames?**
2. In some frames, the `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG` can pick up a vague outline of fish, as shown in the red circle in the pic below: [image: red circle] **Is there any method to fill up that spotted outline and identify it as a fish?**

Here is the link of [my code](https://github.com/jundongq/Object-Tracking/blob/master/FishDetection.py).

Thank you!

Comment: use threshold of direct frame differences: cv::absdiff (frame1,frame2) > T in the first few frames or better (absdiff(frame1,frame2)>T) && (absdiff(ftame2,frame3)>T)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the fish swim along only this direction (or the opposite), you can try to use custom morphological operations that help to grow elongated objects. It should at least increase the size of the blob, thereby giving more data to the MoG model for tracking.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, most time, the fish swim along the direction against the movement of particles. What your suggested is to elongate all objects before applying MOG? Do you have any suggestions on the morphological kernel to elongate objects?

Comment: Even dilation followed by erosion should connect parts of these blobs. You will have to experiment with the kernels, though. I haven't tried them recently so it is hard to give straight suggestions.